# Why do cv-qualifiers get removed from function return type in some cases?

Tags: c++, constants, value-categories

Look at this simple example:

```
template <typename T>
const T const_create() {
    return T();
}

struct Foo { };

int main() {
    auto &x = const_create<Foo>(); // compiles
    // auto &x = const_create<int>(); // doesn't compile
}
```

Why does the version with `Foo` compile, but with `int` doesn't? In other words, why does `const` get removed from the return type of `const_create<int>`? It works like if it returned `int`, not `const int`. Isn't this an inconsistency in the language?

Where does the standard mandate this behavior?

Comment: Returning a `const` value of *any* type is really moot. Since it's returned by value, the caller could just copy that value into a non-const object anyway and modify that copy as much as the caller wants.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[[expr]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr#6) says:

> If a prvalue initially has the type “*cv* `T`”, where `T` is a
>   cv-unqualified **non-class, non-array type**, the type of the
>   expression is adjusted to `T` prior to any further analysis.

Therefore, the `const Foo` prvalue is just `const Foo`, but `const int` prvalue is adjusted to `int`.

---

This rule is introduced in C++14 (compare [N3337 [basic.lval]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/basic.lval#4) with [N4140 [expr]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/expr#6)) by [CWG 1261](https://wg21.link/cwg1261).

Comment: I'm very curious about the reason of this rule.

Comment: @geza I'm curious too ...  I guess this has something to do with the handling of cv-qualified member functions, but I can't really say for sure.